# css pseudo-element ::selection not working properly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to customise elements selection with this css property :

```css
::selection {
  background: red;
  /*Pantone 2727 C else deepskyblue;*/
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
## **La communauté et Swift au-delà d’Apple**

Apple présente Swift au public à l’occasion de la WWDC 2014, il y a près de cinq ans de cela. C’est Craig Federighi, qui a remplacé Bertrand Serlet en 2011, qui évoque la nouveauté pendant la conférence en décrivant le nouveau langage comme « *Objective-C, sans le C* ». Un slogan accrocheur, reconnaît Chris Lattner, mais qu’il regrette, puisque ce n’était pas l’objectif.<br>
![Craig Federighi](https://cdn.mgig.fr/2019/02/mg-68783194-51b4-42a3-a804-w1000h562-sc.jpg)<span>Craig Federighi, pendant le keynote de la WWDC 2014, introduisant Swift.</span>
```

And it's supposed to be applied to all the selected content on the current page, but it actually break at some point of the markdown when parsed.

[blog article example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMowr.png)

I don't understand what's happening here. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks!

## **Edit**

The problem was caused by markdown parsing, so I separated the images from the text like so :

```
## **La communauté et Swift au-delà d’Apple**

Apple présente Swift au public à l’occasion de la WWDC 2014, il y a près de cinq ans de cela. C’est Craig Federighi, qui a remplacé Bertrand Serlet en 2011, qui évoque la nouveauté pendant la conférence en décrivant le nouveau langage comme « *Objective-C, sans le C* ». Un slogan accrocheur, reconnaît Chris Lattner, mais qu’il regrette, puisque ce n’était pas l’objectif.<br>

![Craig Federighi](https://cdn.mgig.fr/2019/02/mg-68783194-51b4-42a3-a804-w1000h562-sc.jpg)<span>Craig Federighi, pendant le keynote de la WWDC 2014, introduisant Swift.</span>
```

Comment: Maybe some other CSS is overriding yours. Please provide a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: this is working fine, maybe there is something else that causing it

Comment: i have created a code snippet in that it is woking as expected.

Comment: I wanted to make things simpler because it is from a mark-down page converted into HTML and styled with Bulma and then with the custom css I showed you. I'm not sure how I could make a working example of that mess 

Comment: As others said, your problem is most likely not because of your content or your own CSS but caused by all the extra stuff.

Comment: I found out! It was caused by markdown parsing. I used a span tag under images links so I separated images from the article text and it worked fine! I'll paste the source of the problem. Thanks for your help! 